# Symfony 3 : Unable to use Twig in "Create your First Page in Symfony"

Tags: symfony

I'm trying the example in the tutorial. So I created the necessary twig-file in the right directory.

```
{# app/Resources/views/lucky/number.html.twig #}
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<h1>Lucky Numbers: {{ luckyNumberList }}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

But if I open the page I get the error

> Looks like you try to load a template outside configured directories (../base.html.twig) in lucky\number.html.twig at line 2

Anyone who can help me out?

Comment: did you cleared the cache?

Comment: in my project I use `{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}` when the template is inside my bundle.

Comment: Indeed. In my twig-file I had the line {% extends '../base.html.twig' %}. And that gave a problem. Removing ../ resolved the problem. Many thanks for your quick responses.

Answer (score -2):

Firstly remove the ".twig" from "base.html.twig".

Then check that the file "base.html.twig" is at the root of views folder.

In case it is in a nested folder then nested folder is also specified in extends command (check documentation).